# Formatting data in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have few tables and basically I'm working out on telerik reports. The structure and the sample data I have is given below:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Leave'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [Leave];
END;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Addition'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [Addition];
END;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Deduction'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [Deduction];
END;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('EmployeeInfo'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [EmployeeInfo];
END;
GO

CREATE TABLE [EmployeeInfo] (
[EmpID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[EmployeeName] VARCHAR(255)
);


CREATE TABLE [Addition] (
    [AdditionID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [AdditionType] VARCHAR(255), 
    [Amount] VARCHAR(255),
    [EmpID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EmployeeInfo(EmpID)
);


CREATE TABLE [Deduction] (
    [DeductionID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DeductionType] VARCHAR(255), 
    [Amount] VARCHAR(255),
    [EmpID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EmployeeInfo(EmpID)
);


CREATE TABLE [Leave] (
    [LeaveID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [LeaveType] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [DateFrom] VARCHAR(255),
    [DateTo] VARCHAR(255),
    [Approved] Binary,
    [EmpID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EmployeeInfo(EmpID)
);
GO


INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo([EmpID], [EmployeeName]) VALUES
(1, 'Marcia'),
(2, 'Lacey'),
(3, 'Fay'),
(4, 'Mohammad'),
(5, 'Mike')


INSERT INTO Addition([AdditionID], [AdditionType], [Amount], [EmpID]) VALUES
(1, 'Bonus', '2000', 2),
(2, 'Increment', '5000', 5)


INSERT INTO Deduction([DeductionID], [DeductionType], [Amount], [EmpID]) VALUES
(1, 'Late Deductions', '2000', 4),
(2, 'Delayed Project Completion', '5000', 1)


INSERT INTO Leave([LeaveID],[LeaveType],[DateFrom],[DateTo], [Approved], [EmpID]) VALUES
(1, 'Annual Leave','2018-01-08 04:52:03','2018-01-10 20:30:53', 1, 1),
(2, 'Sick Leave','2018-02-10 03:34:41','2018-02-14 04:52:14', 1, 2),
(3, 'Casual Leave','2018-01-04 11:06:18','2018-01-05 04:11:00', 1, 3),
(4, 'Annual Leave','2018-01-17 17:09:34','2018-01-21 14:30:44', 1, 4),
(5, 'Casual Leave','2018-01-09 23:31:16','2018-01-12 15:11:17', 1, 3),
(6, 'Annual Leave','2018-02-16 18:01:03','2018-02-19 17:16:04', 1, 2)
```

The query I am using to get the output is something like this:

```
SELECT  Info.EmployeeName, Addition.AdditionType, Addition.Amount, Deduction.DeductionType, Deduction.Amount,
        Leave.LeaveType, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, Leave.DateFrom, Leave.DateTo)) [#OfLeaves], 
        DatePart(MONTH, Leave.DateFrom)
FROM    EmployeeInfo Info
        LEFT JOIN Leave
          ON Info.EmpID = Leave.EmpID
          LEFT JOIN Addition
          ON Info.EmpID = Addition.EmpID
          LEFT JOIN Deduction
          ON Info.EmpID = Deduction.EmpID
WHERE   Approved = 1 
GROUP   BY Info.EmployeeName, Addition.AdditionType, Addition.Amount, Deduction.DeductionType, Deduction.Amount,
         Leave.LeaveType, 
         DatePart(MONTH, Leave.DateFrom)
```

I actually want to get the output which I could be able to show on the report but somehow as I'm using joins the data is repeating on multiple rows for same user and that's why it's also appearing multiple times on the report.
The output I am getting is something like this

```
Fay         NULL    NULL    NULL                        NULL    Casual Leave    4   1
Lacey       Bonus   2000    NULL                        NULL    Annual Leave    3   2
Lacey       Bonus   2000    NULL                        NULL    Sick Leave      4   2
Marcia      NULL    NULL    Delayed Project Completion  5000    Annual Leave    2   1
Mohammad    NULL    NULL    Late Deductions             2000    Annual Leave    4   1
```

Although what I want it looks something like this:

```
Fay         NULL    NULL    NULL                        NULL    Casual Leave    4   1
Lacey       Bonus   2000    NULL                        NULL    Annual Leave    3   2
Lacey       NULL    NULL    NULL                        NULL    Sick Leave      4   2
Marcia      NULL    NULL    Delayed Project Completion  5000    Annual Leave    2   1
Mohammad    NULL    NULL    Late Deductions             2000    Annual Leave    4   1
```

As there was only one bonus and it was not allocated multiple times than it should appear one time. I am stuck in formatting the table layout so I think I might able to get a hint in formatting the output in query so I won't have to do there.

Best,

Comment: Why do you call _different data_ in output a "formatting" problem?

Comment: `I want it looks something like this: <dup bonus>`, ... `than it should appear one time`. So which one is the right way?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I certainly did not get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own recommendation on this case is to change the left joins to a single table in the following way:

```
select 
info.employeename, additiontype, additionamount, deductiontype, deductionamount, leavetype, #ofleaves, leavemth
from Employeeinfo info
join
(
Select
Leave.empid,  null as additiontype, null as additionamount, null as deductiontype, null as deductionamount, leave.leavetype, DATEDIFF(Day, Leave.DateFrom, Leave.DateTo) [#OfLeaves], DatePart(MONTH, DateFrom) leavemth
  from leave 
where approved = 1
  Union all
 Select 
Addition.empid, additiontype, amount, null, null, null, null, null
From addition
Union all
Select empid, null, null, deductiontype, amount, null, null, null
From deduction
  ) payadj on payadj.empid= info.empid
```

This approach separates the different pay adjustments into the different columns and also ensures that you don't get the double ups where this joins add multiple employee IDs.

You might need to explicitly name all the null columns for each Union - I haven't tested it, but I thought you only need to name the columns in a union all once.

The output comes in the format below;

```
employeename     bonus     leavetype
Lacey            2000      null
Lacey            null      Sick Leave
Lacey            null      Annual Leave
```

Rather than type out the full result set here is a link to sqlfiddle;
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/935e9/5/0

Comment: Could you be able to post the entire query and the result ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm curious about one this that Fay's #ofLeaves should be 4 against Casual Leaves as they are of same type and in same month but they are coming up as 1 and 3.

Comment: Could you add an sqlfiddle. Saves me a bit of thinking

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer if you think the bit you figured out will help someone else in a similar situation

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is based on how you are joining the tables together. It's not syntax that's necessarily wrong but how we look at the data and how we understand the relationships between the tables. When doing the LEFT JOINs your query is able to find EmpIDs in each table and it is happy with that and grabs the records (or returns NULL if there are no records matching the EmpID). That isn't really what you're looking for since it can join too much together. So let's see why this is happening. If we take out the join to the Addition table your results would look like this:

```
Fay         NULL                        NULL    Casual Leave    4   1
Lacey       NULL                        NULL    Annual Leave    3   2
Lacey       NULL                        NULL    Sick Leave      4   2
Marcia      Delayed Project Completion  5000    Annual Leave    2   1
Mohammad    Late Deductions             2000    Annual Leave    4   1
```

You are still left with two rows for Lacey. The reason for these two rows is because of the join to the Leave table. Lacey has taken two leaves of absence. One for Sick Leave and the other for Annual Leave. Both of those records share the same EmpID of 2. So when you join to the Addition table (and/or to the rest of the tables) on EmpID the join looks for all matching records to complete that join. There's a single Addition record that matches two Leave records joined on EmpID. Thus, you end up with two Bonus results--the same Addition record for the two Leave records. Try running this query and check the results, it should also illustrate the problem:

```
SELECT l.LeaveType, l.EmpID, a.AdditionType, a.Amount
FROM Leave l
LEFT JOIN Addition a ON a.EmpID = l.EmpID
```

The results using your provided data would be:

```
Annual Leave    1    NULL        NULL
Sick Leave      2    Bonus       2000
Casual Leave    3    NULL        NULL
Annual Leave    4    NULL        NULL
Casual Leave    3    NULL        NULL
Annual Leave    2    Bonus       2000
```

So the data itself isn't wrong. It's just that when joining on EmpID in this way the relationships may be confusing.

So the problem is the relationship between the Leave table and the others. It doesn't make sense to join Leave to the Addition or Deduction tables directly on EmpID because it may look as though Lacey received a bonus for each leave of absence for example. This is what you are experiencing here.

I would suggest three separate queries (and potentially three reports). One to return the leave of absence data and the others for the Addition and Deduction data. Something like:

```
--Return each employee's leaves of absence
SELECT e.EmployeeName
      , l.LeaveType
      , SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, l.DateFrom, l.DateTo)) [#OfLeaves]
      , DatePart(MONTH, l.DateFrom)
FROM EmployeeInfo e
LEFT JOIN Leave l ON e.EmpID = l.EmpID
WHERE l.Approved = 1 

--Return each employee's Additions
SELECT e.EmployeeName
     , a.AdditionType
     , a.Amount
FROM EmployeeInfo e
LEFT JOIN Addition a ON e.EmpID = a.EmpID

--Return each employee's Deductions
SELECT e.EmployeeName
     , d.DeductionType
     , d.Amount
FROM EmployeeInfo e
LEFT JOIN Deduction d ON e.EmpID = d.EmpID
```

Having three queries should better represent the relationship the EmployeeInfo table has with each of the others and separate concerns. From there you can GROUP BY the different types of data and aggregate the values and get total counts and sums.

Here are some resources which may help if you hadn't found these already:

Explanation of SQL Joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

SQL Join Examples: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Telerik Reporting Documentation: https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/overview

Comment: You have quite explained the situation and I really appreciate that but the point where you said that I still left with 2 rows for Lacey, 2 rows for Lacey is really not the issue right now. The problem is that Lacey was assigned Bonus 1 time. But it is appearing 2 times which it shouldn't as Bonus was assigned to her once.

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo I see where you're coming from. You're right, the two rows for Lacey definitely are correct. The thing is, those two rows have an EmpID of 2 associated with them. So once SQL grabs the values from the Addition table it joins the single record for EmpID = 2 from that table to both Leave records. I added an example in the middle of my answer to illustrate that which I hope better explains the situation.

Comment: I get it that part. I think I'll have to dig deeper in the telerik table structure to find a solution there so I might do the grouping in the tables. I'm quite not sure what is the reason and how can I do that part but let's see what can I do.

Comment: All right, good luck! Definitely check out LJ01's answer which gathers all the data together. Perhaps the output LJ01 listed would work for you. :)

Comment: Thank you and yeah I'm gonna check that one and I guess that'll sort out my issue for a while.
Have a great day anyways :)